# How to write a rule that validates an integer with or without a sign?

Tags: prolog, integer

Here are my test cases. The test case with no sign fails. I can't figure out how to make it pass.

```
[1]  ?- signedIntegerProduction([3,2,2]).
false.

[1]  ?- signedIntegerProduction([+,2,2]).
true.

[1]  ?- signedIntegerProduction([-,2,2]).
true.
```

Here's my rule file:

```
isDigit(0).
isDigit(1).
isDigit(2).
isDigit(3).
isDigit(4).
isDigit(5).
isDigit(6).
isDigit(7).
isDigit(8).
isDigit(9).
isDigit([]).

isSign(-).
isSign(+).
isSign([]).

integerProduction(X) :- 
    isDigit(X).

unsignedIntegerProduction([]).

unsignedIntegerProduction([H|T]) :- 
    isDigit(H), 
    unsignedIntegerProduction(T).

signedIntegerProduction([H|T]) :- 
    isSign(H),
    unsignedIntegerProduction(T).
```

Comment: Do you know about [DCG](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG)s in particular [digit//1](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=digit//1) and friends?

Comment: No, I don't... now I do. I would like see a fix to my code as well. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

You are demanding that a test for a signed integer:

```
signedIntegerProduction([3,2,2]).
```

accept `[3,2,2]` while no sign is given.

This is weird!!

You need another predicate, named `my_integer/1` for example, which tests whether teh argument list is either one of *unsigned* or *signed* integer.

But let's fix more of this by naturally specifying what the "integer" should be.

Below code is more Prolog-idiomatic;

1. No `isFoo/N` naming because, well, everything is a predicate with a boolean outcome anyway. Just `foo/N`.
2. Instead of `CamelCase` naming, `snake_case` naming.
3. Empty lists are *NOT* digits or signs.

```
% Slower but written more compactly than using individual facts.
% N.B. The X are integers, not characters

digit(X)          :- memberchk(X,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).
non_zero_digit(X) :- memberchk(X,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]). 

% Sign is naturally one of two characters

sign(-).
sign(+).

% An "integer" is a "signed integer" or an "unsigned integer".
% Note that integer/1 is already defined by the system, so 
% we use the name my_integer/1

my_integer(List) :- signed_integer(List),!.
my_integer(List) :- unsigned_integer(List).

% A "signed integer" is a "sign" followed by an "unsigned integer"

signed_integer([S|More]) :- sign(S),unsigned_integer(More).

% An "unsigned integer" is a "zero" or a "non-zero digit" followed
% by any "digit sequence" including the empty sequence.

unsigned_integer([0])       :- !.
unsigned_integer([NZ|More]) :- non_zero_digit(NZ),digit_sequence(More).

% A "digit sequence" is a possibly a empty sequence of any "digits".

digit_sequence([]).
digit_sequence([X|More]) :- digit(X),digit_sequence(More).
```

Add some test cases using SWI-Prolog's extremely useful [`plunit`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27)) (plunit or similar testing framework should be the first thing taught in class; these ain't the 90s anymore)

```
:- begin_tests(my_digits).

test(1,fail)  :- my_integer([]).
test(2)       :- my_integer([0]).
test(3)       :- my_integer([+,0]).
test(4)       :- my_integer([-,0]).
test(5,fail)  :- my_integer([0,1,2,3]).
test(6)       :- my_integer([1,2,3]).
test(7)       :- my_integer([+,1,2,3]).
test(8)       :- my_integer([-,1,2,3]).
test(9,fail)  :- my_integer([-,1,2,z]).
test(10,fail) :- my_integer([-]).
test(11,fail) :- my_integer([+]).

:- end_tests(my_digits).
```

And so:

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: my_digits ........... done
% All 11 tests passed
true.
```

Awesome!